# Stored procedure that returns json data

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, select, stored-procedures

I'm pretty much new to SQL and stored procedures in general and I need help creating a stored procedure that would get data from database.

Here is my e-r diagram

[image]

What I need to do, is get out all rented movies for each and every customer that is currently logged in.

Here is example:

**Customer**:

```
Id: 1
Name: Jack
Last name: Jackson

Id: 2
Name: John
Last name: Jankins
```

**Movie**

```
Id: 1
Title: Logan
Serial num: 19946519

Id: 2
Title: Shutter island
Serial num: 23456519

Id: 3
Title: Pulp fiction
Serial num: 11934857
```

Result:

- RentedMovies for customer with id 1: (movies with id 1 and 2)

RentedMovies

```
Id: 1
Name: John
Last name: Jankins
Title: Logan
Serial num: 19946519
Category: Action
Type: Limited release

Id: 2
Name: John
Last name: Jankins
Title: Shutter island
Serial num: 23456519
Category: Mystery
Type: Limited release
```

I'm not sure whether `RentedMovies` should both have Id of 1, but I think you get the picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

This is what I've got so far, but it's not working. Plus I have no idea how to make it return as JSON.

```
SELECT 
    rm.id, c.name, c.lastName, m.title, m.serialNumber, cat.category, t.type
FROM 
    RentedMovies rm
INNER JOIN  
    Customer c ON c.id = rm.fk_Customer,
INNER JOIN  
    Movies m ON m.id = rm.fk_Movie
INNER JOIN  
    Category cat ON cat.id = mc.fk_Category
INNER JOIN  
    Type t ON t.Id = mt.fk_Type
WHERE 
    c.id = Id;
```

I would really appreciate your help!

PS: this is an ASP.NET MVC app, and results should be based on user's currently logged in ID, which gets passed from code-behind.

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? SQL Server **2016** and newer have a `FOR JSON` keyword to convert a result set to JSON directly (see [MSDN docs on creating JSON responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) )

Comment: it is 2016 indeed @marc_s

Answer (score 4):

This Should work!

```
Create Proc RentedFilms (
@ID
) AS

 SELECT 
 CM.id
,CM.name
,CM.lastName
,MV.title
,MV.serialNumber
,CG.category
,TP.type
FROM RentedMovie RM
LEFT JOIN Customer CM on RM.fk_Customer=CM.id
LEFT JOIN Movie MV on  RM.fk_Movie=MV.id
RIGHT JOIN MovieCategory  MC on MC.fk_Movie=MV.id
LEFT JOIN Category CG on CG.id=MC.fk_Category
RIGHT JOIN MovieType MT on MT.fk_Movie=MV.id
LEFT JOIN Type TP on TP.id=MT.fk_Type
WHERE CM.id=@ID
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: Impressive first answer. I cannot verify that it is working because I have no clue about this topic, but it looks good :) Welcome to Stackoverflow!